# Kali Cannot Boot

Tags: kali-linux, usb-drive, live-usb

My PC has no HDD. I've installed Kali onto USB stick located in USB port 1 (`/dev/sda`). Kali installation media was in USB port 2 (`/dev/sdb`). Installation was successful.

When I put my USB stick with Kali installation in USB port 1 (`/dev/sda`) it boots just fine. But when I put it in USB port 2 or USB port 3, it fails to boot.

Also when I try to put this USB stick in another PC which has HDD installed (`/dev/sda`), it also fails to boot. But when I remove HDD drive from that particular PC and try to boot from my USB stick, it boots.

This is the error i'm getting:

```
[    4.217127] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    4.217223] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/sda1 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Debian 1:1.27.2-1) built-in-shell (ash)
Enter `help` for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

How do I fix this so my USB stick with Kali will boot from any USB port?

I don't think my question is duplicate. The problem I have is that when my `/dev/sda` changes to `/dev/sdb` I can no longer boot `/dev/sdb`, but when it goes back to `/dev/sda` it boots fine. I've tried the following steps so far:
1. I've checked if /etc/fstab contains any references to `/dev/sda`. It doesn't. It uses UUID to mount root partition.

Comment: That is somewhat expect behaviour.

Comment: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/321862/93232

Answer (score 2):

So... you installed Kali onto a flash drive from another flash drive? Here are my suggestions, because it is doubtful anyone will walk you through this:

- Look into how to run Kali with persistence on a flash drive. There really is no need to be installing the OS on the flash drive, especially for what Kali is intended for. If not: (Again, this is the best solution)

  - Have you done any research on the obvious error output? It even lists common solutions. Attempt those and go from there. Do some research on the concepts of mounting/partitions/etc before jumping to reaching out for help. This is a general concept to live by for anything in the tech world.
  - Have you *ever* used Linux before? If not, I'd recommend not jumping straight into Kali. Don't be *that* person who jumps into Kali with no prior experience, and then flood forums with basic Linux questions ("How do I run commands? Why can't this script I copied execute?")

Takeaway: Jumping into Linux without researching problems and understanding core concepts is not the way to go. Enjoy learning so many new things and good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've been using GNU/Linux for 8 years. I don't think it's an obvious error because my auto-generated /etc/fstab contains only references by UUID, and all solutions on the internet to "/dev/sda1 does not exist" mention only changing GRUB config to point to /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sda. They do not mention how to make USB universally bootable.